# How to make multiple animation for an object by multiple image in Corona SDK?

Tags: animation, coronasdk, sprite-sheet

I just learned programming with Corona SDK. Recently I have a problem in animate the object. I have seen all the instructions about animation in Corona and I saw it just present about how to make animation for object with a single image (they use one image to make the object have two or more animation) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VsA2agBAWho&t=322s.

I have followed suit and the problem begin when I find the asset on the Internet, the link here: https://finalbossblues.itch.io/pixel-platformer-pack?download. As you can see, the folder have multiple image for multiple animation. I have no idea and no reference to animate all the animation for my player by multiple image (but I can do that with a single image).

I have found some solutions on the Internet but there no result suitable for me.

As the result, I have the following code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- main.lua
--
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- My code here

local sheetData = {
    width = 30,
    height = 44,
    numFrames = 6,
    sheetContentWidth = 181,
    sheetContentHeight = 44 }

local mySheet = graphics.newImageSheet( "walk.png", sheetData )

local sequenceData = {
    { name = "normalrun", start = 1, count = 6, time = 800 } 
  }

local animation = display.newSprite( mySheet, sequenceData )
animation.x=150
animation.y= 300
animation:play()
```

This just makes one animation.

And now, I just have two ways to choose. One is use some method to animate multiple animation by multiple image (this is where I need assistance). Two is combine all image to one.

I use GG Translate for this question. This is my first step in game development. I want to integrated all animation into my player (like walk, jump, attack...) and call it to use when I want ( with multiple Image).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[display.newSprite()](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newSprite.html)

Look at the sample code called "Multiple Image Sheets".

Everything you need is in the Corona Api Documentation :)

> just make 1 animation :((

Add `loop = 0` in each anim to your sequenceData if you need to loop indefinitly

> Two is combine all image to one :)) ( look so cheat ).

If your images are not too big you can put a lot in one sheet, just control his dimension to don't have a huge one

Comment: WOW! It so useful and easy. The example is so easy to understand,yet I have not known for a long time. Thanks you so much :))